# How to put a component object into a global window variable in Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

In Vue2 (Options API) I put `this` into a window variable for some components, so I can easily test methods and find out what property values are from a Dev Tools console.
For example in my main page component I simply do:

```
mounted() {
  window.mainpage = this
}
```

This way when I want to run a method from the console, I can easily do:

```
mainpage.somemethod()
```

or `mainpage.someproperty` to get the value of that property.

I can't figure out how to do this in Vue3 with the Composition API. I've already looked into `getCurrentInstance()` but this doesn't seem to be the same kind of object as in Vue2. Somehow the methods and properties of the component aren't in this object.

Any ideas how to get this to work or another way to debug a component from the console?

***UPDATE***
I think I found a solution:

in `setup()`:

```
  const instance = getCurrentInstance();
```

in `onMounted()`

```
  window.mainpage = instance.ctx;
```

The `ctx` does the trick. Now in the devtools console you can access properties and execute methods of the component, but only those that were returned in `setup`.

Comment: Can you provide some code? I [threw together this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82x6L9d4/) which seems to work OK

Comment: Hi, I forget to mention I'm trying this with the Composition API.

Comment: The `setup` method of the composition API does not have a reference to the component as the component has not yet been created. Instead, return any of the properties you define in `setup`  and the binding you apply in `mounted` will give you the correct access. [Here's a jsfiddle for you](https://jsfiddle.net/6jhyr7ez/)

Comment: I'm sorry, I only know how to use SFC  (`.vue` files) for components. I use `onMounted()`  (Composition API), in which `window.mainpage = this` doesn't seem to work (undefined).

Comment: FWIW, this is rarely ever needed with Vue devtools. They allow to access component instance in console. You can do `window.mainpage = getCurrentInstance()` in setup (not onMounted). You may have problems with this because composition API is functional and not everything is exposed.

Comment: I updated my question with a workable solution. BTW, I find Vue Devtools unusable, but maybe that's just me. I would like to be able to execute component methods with different arguments and couldn't figure out how to do this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `setup()` method, try:

```js
setup() {
   ...
   window.mainpage = getCurrentInstance().proxy
   ...
}
```

You can also call `getCurrentInstance` from inside the Vue3 lifecycle callbacks.

Comment: Somehow , `proxy` seems to be the same as the `ctx` property ?

Comment: `proxy` should be the same instance you get calling `this` inside a Vue2 method.